# 404 on sudo apt-get update 404 not found chris-lea/node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, apt

I'm trying to use

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 
$ sudo apt-get update
```

to install and update an npm and nodejs

Most of the references to this repository I've found are out of date from 2011-2013

I get a 404 error during `$ sudo apt-get update` to the link

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages 404 Not found
```

Is there a more updated version of this?

Comment: `wheezy` is not a valid Ubuntu version. Are you mixing Ubuntu and Debian instructions?

Comment: As @tripleee said, `wheezy` is not a valid Ubuntu version, and Launchpad doesn't offer Debian binaries nor armhf packages.

Comment: Actually a Launchpad PPA could offer whatever the Launchpad user put there; and Ubuntu packages *are* Debian packages. But the `armhf` observation is probably correct; most often, you'll only find packages for the `i386` and/or `x64` architectures.

Comment: The repo in my answer *does* appear to include armhf builds of node-js 0.12; see https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/63#issuecomment-78424051

Comment: @tripleee "Ubuntu packages are Debian packages" actually, Ubuntu code base has diverged so much that isn't anymore binary compatible. So, I wouldn't suggest anyone to use Debian packages on a Ubuntu installation, or vice-versa.

Comment: There are situations where that won't work, yes; but as a matter of fact, the repo we are discussing has one repo for Debian and Ubuntu and identical instructions for both. The day Ubuntu ships a radically different libc6 is still far away.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager has instructions for a repository which supersedes the old PPA. (For me, this is the top Google hit for [node-js ppa](https://www.google.com/search?q=node-js+ppa).)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

(I don't particularly recommend running stuff you download without auditing it first, nor have I tried these instructions.)

Answer (score 1):

The [nodejs](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nodejs/) and [npm](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/npm/) package are included in the wheezy/main repository.

In order to install npm and nodejs on raspbian you should include in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main
```

Next you should be able to install nodejs and npm using :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install npm nodejs
```

Comment: i get a `E: Unable to locate package node-js`

Comment: Then that is the crucial detail you should have in your answer, not the trivial command you can then obviously use.

Comment: @tripleee : I improved the answer following your suggestion. As this is the intial configuration of `/etc/apt/source.list` in raspbian, I was wondering it was like this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I could work around it changing the source to the previous Ubuntu version.

So, from this:
`http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu vivid main`

To this:
`http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu utopic main`